# Cannot select the column I am using to group by

Tags: mysql

I have this query, which is working fantastically but there is one small problem.

What this query is doing is squashing all the dates into their respective month and then getting the average of the values that fall in that month.

```
SELECT CAST(AVG(GASVBR) as DECIMAL(10,3)) as "Gas", CAST(AVG(OLVBR) as DECIMAL(10, 3)) as "Oil", CAST(AVG(STROVBR) as DECIMAL(10,3)) as "Strom" 
FROM TABLENAME 
GROUP BY YEAR(PRSD#), MONTH(PRSD#)
```

I'd like to include the `PRSD#` (which is the date) alongside these outputted averages.
As I understand it the problem is I cannot just include the `PRSD#` in the select statement because it would then output every date, not just the months.

So my question is: How could I output the `PRSD#` alongside the averages to keep the data understandable? :)

Unfortunately

```
SELECT GROUP BY (YEAR(PRSD#, MONTH(PRSD#)) as "Datum" CAST(AVG(GASVBR) as DECIMAL(10,3)) as "Gas", CAST(AVG(OLVBR) as DECIMAL(10, 3)) as "Oil", CAST(AVG(STROVBR) as DECIMAL(10,3)) as "Strom" 
FROM TABLENAME 
GROUP BY YEAR(PRSD#), MONTH(PRSD#)
```

is not working, would greatly appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: Select the columns in the group by clause: `SELECT YEAR(PRSD#), MONTH(PRSD#), CAST(AVG(GASVBR) as DECIMAL(10,3)) as "Gas", .....`

Comment: Wow yeah that pretty much did it, is there a way to concatenate two Selects into one field? Youre a boss forpas

Comment: Use the function CONCAT(): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat like `CONCAT(YEAR(PRSD#), '-',MONTH(PRSD#))`

Comment: Hmm I will have to play with it, its acting weird :) but thanks for the pointers ! Have a nice day